# Transactional memory

Tags: computer-architecture

I would like to understand what role does Transactional memory plays in memory organization, I know that To allow for more efficient parallel programming with higher performance, processor implements a hardware transactional memory facility.

But I would like to know what the processor do for memory management when there is also a Transactional memory?

For eg. Consider the Transactional memory in Power8 processor.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make it any more specific?  I'm not sure what you mean by "what role does Transactional memory plays in memory organization" or by "what the processor do for memory management when there is also a Transactional memory".  It might also help to tell us your thoughts and your motivation.

Comment: Does it play a role? I thought it was mainly a fad of the early 2000s that never went anywhere. I remember Cliff Click talking about how they added TM to the Azul Vega-3 CPU, but benchmarks then showed it didn't make any difference. The only reason they didn't remove it again was that they had already designed and implemented it, and it also didn't hurt performance. And it looked cool on data sheets to say "we support TM".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory